# A better/faster way to handle human names in Pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with a large amount of data that includes the standard five columns for human names (prefix, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix) and I would like to merge them in a separate column as a readable name. The issue I have is with handling blank values - the issue creates spacing problems. Also, I cannot modify the original columns. My current process feels a little insane (but it works!) so I am looking for a more elegant solution.

My current code:

```
def add_space_prefix(x):
    x = str(x)
    if len(x) > 0:
        return x + ' '
    else:
        return x


def add_space_middle(x):
    x = str(x)
    if len(x) > 0:
        return ' ' + x
    else:
        return x


def add_space_suffix(x):
    x = str(x)
    if len(x) > 0:
        return ', ' + x
    else:
        return x`

df["middlename"] = 
df["middlename"].map(lambda x: add_space_middle(x))
df["prefix"] = df["prefix"].map(lambda x: add_space_prefix(x))
df["suffix"] = df["suffix"].map(lambda x: add_space_suffix(x))
df['fullname'] = df["prefix"] + df["firstname"] + df[
        "middlename"] + ' ' + df["lastname"] + df['suffix']
```

Sample Dataframe

```
    prefix  firstname   middlename  lastname    suffix  fullname
0           Michael                 Hobart      Jr.     Michael Jobart, Jr.
1   Mr.     Alan                    Lilt                Mr. Alan Lilt
2           Jon         A.          Smith       III     Jon A. Smith, III
3           Joe                     Miller              Joe Miller
4           Mika        Jennifer    Shabosky            Mika Jennifer Shabosky
5   Mrs.    Angela                  Calder              Mrs. Angela Calder
6           Boris       Al          Bert        Esq.    Boris Al Bert, Esq.
7   Dr.     Natasha                 Chorus              Dr. Natasha Chorus
8           Bill                    Gibbons             Bill Gibbons
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example. We don't have your dataframe. It is very easy to provide a small example.

Comment: When you say blank, is it NaN or empty string?

Comment: Blank as in empty string.

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**
*`' '.join` and `pd.Series.str`*
In this solution we join the entire row by spaces.  This may lead to spaces at the beginning or end of the string or with 2 or more spaces in the middle.  We handle this by chaining string accessor methods.

```
df.assign(
    lastname=df.lastname + ','
).apply(' '.join, 1).str.replace('\s+', ' ').str.strip(' ,')

0       Michael Hobart, Jr.
1             Mr. Alan Lilt
2         Jon A. Smith, III
3                Joe Miller
4    Mika Jennifer Shabosky
5        Mrs. Angela Calder
6       Boris Al Bert, Esq.
7        Dr. Natasha Chorus
8              Bill Gibbons
dtype: object
```

---

```
df['fullname'] = df.assign(
    lastname=df.lastname + ','
).apply(' '.join, 1).str.replace('\s+', ' ').str.strip(' ,')
df

  prefix firstname middlename  lastname suffix                fullname
0          Michael               Hobart    Jr.     Michael Hobart, Jr.
1    Mr.      Alan                 Lilt                  Mr. Alan Lilt
2              Jon         A.     Smith    III       Jon A. Smith, III
3              Joe               Miller                     Joe Miller
4             Mika   Jennifer  Shabosky         Mika Jennifer Shabosky
5   Mrs.    Angela               Calder             Mrs. Angela Calder
6            Boris         Al      Bert   Esq.     Boris Al Bert, Esq.
7    Dr.   Natasha               Chorus             Dr. Natasha Chorus
8             Bill              Gibbons                   Bill Gibbons
```

---

**Option 2**
list comprehension
In this solution, we perform the same activities as with the first solution, but we bundle the string operations together and within a comprehension.

```
[re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', ' '.join(s)).strip(' ,')
 for s in df.assign(lastname=df.lastname + ',').values.tolist()]

['Michael Hobart, Jr.',
 'Mr. Alan Lilt',
 'Jon A. Smith, III',
 'Joe Miller',
 'Mika Jennifer Shabosky',
 'Mrs. Angela Calder',
 'Boris Al Bert, Esq.',
 'Dr. Natasha Chorus',
 'Bill Gibbons']
```

---

```
df['fullname'] = [re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', ' '.join(s)).strip(' ,')
                  for s in df.assign(lastname=df.lastname + ',').values.tolist()]
df

  prefix firstname middlename  lastname suffix                fullname
0          Michael               Hobart    Jr.     Michael Hobart, Jr.
1    Mr.      Alan                 Lilt                  Mr. Alan Lilt
2              Jon         A.     Smith    III       Jon A. Smith, III
3              Joe               Miller                     Joe Miller
4             Mika   Jennifer  Shabosky         Mika Jennifer Shabosky
5   Mrs.    Angela               Calder             Mrs. Angela Calder
6            Boris         Al      Bert   Esq.     Boris Al Bert, Esq.
7    Dr.   Natasha               Chorus             Dr. Natasha Chorus
8             Bill              Gibbons                   Bill Gibbons
```

---

**Option 3**
*`pd.replace` and `pd.DataFrame.stack`*
This one is a bit different in that we replace blanks `''` with `np.nan` so that when we `stack` the `np.nan` are naturally dropped.  This makes for the joining with `' '` more straight forward.

```
df.assign(
    lastname=df.lastname + ','
).replace('', np.nan).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join).str.strip(',')

0       Michael Hobart, Jr.
1             Mr. Alan Lilt
2         Jon A. Smith, III
3                Joe Miller
4    Mika Jennifer Shabosky
5        Mrs. Angela Calder
6       Boris Al Bert, Esq.
7        Dr. Natasha Chorus
8              Bill Gibbons
dtype: object
```

---

```
df['fullname'] = df.assign(
    lastname=df.lastname + ','
).replace('', np.nan).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join).str.strip(',')
df

  prefix firstname middlename  lastname suffix                fullname
0          Michael               Hobart    Jr.     Michael Hobart, Jr.
1    Mr.      Alan                 Lilt                  Mr. Alan Lilt
2              Jon         A.     Smith    III       Jon A. Smith, III
3              Joe               Miller                     Joe Miller
4             Mika   Jennifer  Shabosky         Mika Jennifer Shabosky
5   Mrs.    Angela               Calder             Mrs. Angela Calder
6            Boris         Al      Bert   Esq.     Boris Al Bert, Esq.
7    Dr.   Natasha               Chorus             Dr. Natasha Chorus
8             Bill              Gibbons                   Bill Gibbons
```

---

**Timing**
bundling within a comprehension is fastest!

```
%timeit df.assign(fullname=df.replace('', np.nan).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join))
%timeit df.assign(fullname=df.apply(' '.join, 1).str.replace('\s+', ' ').str.strip())
%timeit df.assign(fullname=[re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', ' '.join(s)).strip() for s in df.values.tolist()])

100 loops, best of 3: 2.51 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 979 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 384 µs per loop
```

Comment: What about the comma before the suffix? (e.g. `Jon A. Smith, III` vs. `Jon A. Smith III`).  I think the guy wants the suffix comma.

Comment: @NickBraunagel Glad I could help.